# Sinatra/Ruby DynamoDB get_item returning '#' sign instead of integers

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, httpwebrequest, sinatra, amazon-dynamodb

I am using a Sinatra app to retrieve an item from DynamoDB. I am receiving # signs where integers are stored. I am using the most recent AWS SDK. hk is my hash key. This may be done with the newer version.

My DynamoDB looks like this:

```
   hk         A         B

2015-06-13    4         4
```

My code in my route looks like:

```
  resp = dynamo_client.get_item(
 # required
  table_name: "test",
  # required
  key: {
    "hk" => Date.today.to_s 
  })
  resp.data[:item]
```

What I get when hitting the URL is:

```
["A", #]["hk", "2015-06-13"]["B", #]
```

Why do I get the '#' signs instead of the values?